# The phrase "look out to something"

Tags: phrase-request

I have always used:

> **Look at** the mountains.

Today I saw a sentence:

> **Look out to** the mountains.

Online dictionaries have nothing to say about this. They only have **look out** to mean **watch out.**

But I found a lot of sentences with **look out to** on *Ludwig,* and most of them are associated with natural sights like, **sea, ocean, landscape, etc.**

How should I use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In that context, ‘look out’ is similar to ‘look out from’, indicating that you’re enclosed in something — a train, a house, a plane — and ‘to’ in ‘look out to’ is used to indicate that something is distant. So it’s ‘look out [from what we are in] to x’, where x is something far away.

So if you’re on a boat, and you see an island in the distance, you might say to another passenger, ‘look out to that little island!’ In this, you’re saying ‘look out *from the boat* to that little island’.

The reason it’s often used for natural sights is because generally you view them *from* something, and from far away.

Hope that helps!